# powershell how to find out if a variable is part of another variable

Tags: powershell

I have pasted my code below and pulled out everything that is already working, so I only have the part that isn't working as intended.

I am trying to put the `EmployeeID`, from a csv, in front of the `Description` field in AD.  I can get that part to work, but the beginning of the `If` statement where I try to check if the `$ID` is already in the description fails; it just keeps adding it every time the script runs.

I have tried making both the `$ID` and `$Description` type as string with `Out-String`, and I have left that out, but it's the same result. I have tried `-notcontains`, `-notmatch`, and `-notlike` (which I believe is the correct one to use), but none work. I have even put my variables in a text file to make sure they are pulling the correct information.

I am still learning all of the intricacies of Powershell.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Get script Start Time (used to measure run time)
$startDTM = (Get-Date)

#Null out variables
$Users = $Null
$ID = $Null

$Users = Import-Csv .\ImportADUsers\Test-Import-user-data.csv

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$path = Split-Path -parent ".\ImportADUsers\*.*"

#Create log date
$logdate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd-THH.mm.ss

$logfile = $path + "\logs\$logdate.logfile.txt"

# Enumerate the users, one line at a time.
# This assumes the first line is a header line defining the fields.
ForEach ($User In $Users)
{
    # Retrieve values from the csv.
    $ID = $User.HRRef

         # Retrieve the sAMAccountName of the user from AD.
    $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=$ID)").sAMAccountName
    $ID | Out-File $logfile -Append
    $IDString = $ID | Out-String

    #Retrieve the Description of the user from AD.
    $Description = Get-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Properties description
    $Description = $Description.description | Out-String
    $Description | Out-File $logfile -Append

# Make sure there is only one user with this employeeID.
    If ($UserDN.Count -eq 1)
    {

       IF ($Description -notlike $IDString) {Set-ADUser -Identity $UserDN 
           -Description "$($ID) - $($Description)" } 

    }
    Else {"User with ID $ID either not found, or more than one user found." 
    | Out-File $logfile -Append}
    #Log error for users that are not in Active Directory or EmployeeID 
    #found more than once
}
#Finish
#The lines below calculates how long it takes to run this script
# Get End Time
$endDTM = (Get-Date)

# Echo Time elapsed
"Elapsed Time: $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalminutes) minutes"

#Append the minutes value to the text file

"Import took $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalminutes) minutes to complete." | 
 Out-File $logfile -Append
 #SCRIPT ENDS
```

Comment: Oh, I thought the -like and -notlike were the wildcards, I changed it to

Comment: Oh, I thought the -like and -notlike were the wildcards, I changed it to
    IF ($Description -notlike "*$ID*") {Set-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Description "$($ID) - $($Description)" }
but it still adds the employeeID again at the begining. I took out the first * so it's "$ID*" and now it appears to be working as intended. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you have tried and how it did not work. Reading code in comments is the suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string comparison is incorrect.  Below is how to fix it.

The change: `-notlike $IDString => -notlike "*$ID*"`

```
ForEach ($User In $Users)
{
    # Retrieve values from the csv.
    $ID = $User.HRRef
    $ID | Out-File $logfile -Append

    # Retrieve the SAMAccountName of the user from AD.
    $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=$ID)").SAMAccountName

    #Retrieve the Description of the user from AD.
    $Description = (Get-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Properties description).Description
    $Description | Out-File $logfile -Append

    # Make sure there is only one user with this employeeID.
    If ($UserDN.Count -eq 1 -and $Description -notlike "*$IDString*")
    {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Description "$ID - $Description"
    }
    Else
    {
        "User with ID $ID either not found, or more than one user found." | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
}
```